# rbind fails to bind datetime column

Tags: r, datetime

I am binding a number of data frames  data frames and have noticed that I get weird values in one of the bindings. Datetime in second df is disturbed after binding, it is one hour less than in original df.

```
    kk <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1499133600, 1499137200, 1499140800, 
1499144400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    temp = c(14.7, 14.6, 14.3, 14.2)), .Names = c("date", "temp"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))   
ff <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1499144400, 1499148000, 1499151600, 
1499155200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), temp = 14:17), .Names = c("date", 
"temp"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Calling functions from different packages give me same result:

```
dplyr:: bind_rows(kk, ff)
data.table::rbindlist(list(kk, ff))
rbind(kk,ff)
```

I do not get what is going on. Could it have something to do with date format?

Comment: can you post error code ?

Comment: I am guessing there is no error code. So, m_c_ when I did this, I had a difference of +4 hours. And, given that I am at -4:00 UTC, and we row bound to a UTC standard, it converted to UTC so that ALL of the times in the data frame are from the same zone..are you by any chance at one hour east of the prime meridian, where R would use your system time for the unspecified zone and then subtract one?

Comment: As you can see in the `structure` objects, in the first dataframe your datetimes have the attribute `tzone = "UTC"` whereas in the second one it is `tzone = ""`, so they are interpreted as being in local time.

Comment: Makes sence, thanks!

Comment: Great observation by @sconfluentus.  I'm at +10 UTC and the difference is...10 hours